# How to get tweets older than a specific id in Spring Social

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social

Currently the method 
`List<Tweet> tweets = twitter.timelineOperations().getUserTimeline(screen_name);` 
will fetch the 20 latest tweets. How do i get tweets later than that?

Note: The method `getUserTimeline` can get tweets between two id's and also everything before(read recent) a tweet id. There is no way to get say 20,20 tweets at a time after(read older) a specific tweet id. Is there no way to do this using Spring Social or will I have to implement the Twitter API's myself?

Comment: Check the api documentaion http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/TimelineOperations.html#getMentions(int, long, long) . This might help you out. Read getMentions(int, long, long) methos.

Comment: @zombie I think you didn't understand what I wanted exactly. Currently `getUserTimeline(screen_name)` get the first 20 tweets from a user's timeline. How do I get the next 20 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I fixed it.
`List<Tweet> tweets = twitter.timelineOperations().getUserTimeline(screen_name, 20, 0, Long.parseLong(lowestTweetId));`
Just giving the since_id as 0 and the lowestTweetId, you can get the next 20 tweets of timeline.